# mknfsmnt fails with "System call error number -1"

Tags: networking, nfs, aix, cluster

This system is part of a cluster and the other node mounts the nfs share successfully. This is currently the active node which means it has a secondary service ip address. I think this is related to the issue because I added the service ip to the nfs server /etc/hosts and it mounted fine. That is not a solution though. Why is a cluster ip confusing nfs?

Edit: How does clustering complicate reverse lookup in relation to nfs?

```
# mknfsmnt -f "/mksysb" -d "/export/mksysb" -h "10.0.28.119" '-n' '-N' '-a' -t 'rw' -w 'fg' '-Y' '-Z' '-X' '-H' '-j' '-q' '-g'
nfsmnthelp: 1831-019 10.0.28.119: System call error number -1.

mount: 1831-008 giving up on:
10.0.28.119:/export/mksysb
System call error number -1.

# showmount -e 10.0.28.119
export list for 10.0.28.119:
/export/mksysb *.domain.com
```

Comment: On topic, but you need to edit your question, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a PTR record issue. Reverse lookup failed when doing an nslookup to the IP. I had to have the PTR records added to the DNS server:

```
(root) $ nslookup hostname-svc
Server:         10.48.161.150
Address:        10.48.161.150#53

Name:   hostname-svc
Address: 10.48.151.171

(root) $ nslookup 10.48.151.171
Server:         10.48.161.150
Address:        10.48.161.150#53

**server can't find 171.151.48.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN**
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you answered your own question already with the /etc/hosts entry. I suggest looking at your working nodes and try to find any difference or discrepancy in the nfs server's resolution.

Comment: Name resolution works great though from both sides. Also, this isn't our only cluster so it's not a universal config problem. Google hasn't been very helpful for this specific problem. I guess I'll look into rpc a little more.

Comment: This ended up being a Reverse lookup issue